# Proof of this theorem: $ tr(A^-)=\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i^{-1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with $r$ nonzero characteristic roots $ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_r$ then

$$ {\rm tr}(A^-)=\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i^{-1}. $$

Note:  $A^-$ is generalized inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume "generalized inverse" is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.
Both sides are invariant under unitary transformations, and they are equal for diagonal matrices.

Comment: Generalized inverse is a matrix satisfying $AA^{-}A=A$. It is weaker than Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Comment: If that's all you require, then the result will be false.  For example, if $A$ is diagonal it doesn't restrict $A^-_{i,i}$ when $A_{i,i} = 0$.